# Php image type upload problems gif png

Tags: php, png, jpeg, gif

I have this part of code, and I tried few things like "or" and "else" but it didn't work correctly for me. So atm it works for .jpg file format, and uploads it fine, when I tried to add .gif with limitation of 1-2mb it didn't upload it. Can you help?

```
if (($ext == "jpg") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 350000))
```

I used

```
if (($ext == "gif") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/gif") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 2000000))
```

for gifs and

```
if (($ext == "png") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/png") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 1000000))
```

but it didn't work, so if someone can help me out please =)

Full part of that code for just jpeg was:

```
if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0)) {
                  //Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 350Kb
                  $filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
                  $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
                  if (($ext == "jpg") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 350000)){
                    //Determine the path to which we want to save this file
                      $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upimg/'.$filename;
                      //Check if the file with the same name is already exists on the server
                      if (!file_exists($newname)) {
                        //Attempt to move the uploaded file to it's new place
                        if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$newname))) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the settings in `php.ini` file:

```
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
```

If max sizes are too small then files will not be uploaded.  Increase the size and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot about it!